# How do I lock the position of a game object in Unity, regardless of resolution?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, position, resolution

I am currently making an FPS shooter game in Unity. I have my gun as a child of the main camera. I can see the gun just fine in game, however whenever I change the resolution of my game, the position of my gun is all weird, and sometimes I cannot even see my weapon. Is there a way to lock a game object to the bottom right of the screen, regardless of the resolution?